# How to return an arrayList element in a method?

Tags: java, oop

I have a Repertory class that contains a list of files and inside this  repertory class I want to write a method that return a file with a specific name . I tried this but it didn't work . your help would be appreciated 
ps: the code is not complete . I just gave you an idea of it .

```
class File{ name, ........}

class Repertory {
    fichiers = new ArrayList<File>();

    public File get_File(String fileName){
        File f;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.files.size(); i++) {
            if(this.files.get(i).name.equals(fileName)) {
                f = this.files.get(i);
                return (f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it says "This method must return a result of type File"

Comment: Make sure to properly indent your code. It makes it easier to read, understand, and easier to spot errors (like the missing return after the loop)

Comment: You are only returning from within the if, you need to return something after loop finishes, in order to cover cases where the file you are looking for is not found.

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow handle the situation when the file does not exist - therefore you need to either throw exception (maybe not the best solution but also possible) or return some special "marker object" indicating that file was not found

I think that returning **null** is bad idea and an indicator of bad design - just think about all NPE situation you will need to remember about in the future

Better is to return *Optional* (if you have older JDK than 8, you can use Guava)

```
public Optional<File> get_File(String fileName){
    for (int i = 0; i < this.files.size(); i++) {
        if(this.files.get(i).name.equals(fileName)) {
            return Optional.of(this.files.get(i));
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

and then just handle this when calling

```
get_File("filename").orElse(...) // or even .orElseThrow(...)
```

Answer (score -1):

try something like this:

```
public File get_File(String fileName){
    File f = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
        if(files.get(i).name.equals(fileName)) {
            f = files.get(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    return f;
}
```

you were getting that error because you had a return path that was not returning anything if a file was not found.  Now, when a file is found, the loop exits after assigning the file name to f.  If you do not want to return null to indicate no file, you can also raise an exception.

Other than for exceptions, it is better to have a single point of exit in the method.  Having a bunch of returns everywhere makes the code harder to understand and maintain.

Comment: Or just add `return null` after the loop. Better to keep scopes free of variables, when you don't need them, it is usually less mental overhead. Having to juggle in your mind many variables and backtracking where they have been set and which value they will eventually be assigned is IMHO more difficult to understand and debug (Especially when your method only contains a single loop with an early exit).